# Sum of multiple column values for each row in d3.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, d3.js

I am using a .csv file which requires to find sum of the multiple column values against each key in each row. The example is as below-

```
key  | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 
-----+--------+--------+--------+--------
mike | 1      | 3      | 5      | 7      
-----+--------+--------+--------+--------
mila | 2      | 4      | 6      | 8
-----+--------+--------+--------+--------
minda| 9      | 11     | 13     | 15
```

So I need to find the sum of "value1 + value2 + value3 + value4" against each key in a dynamic way rather mentioning d.value1 + d.value2 + d.value3 + d.value4.

Thanks...

Comment: No if it only possible with d3.js then it is more better..

Comment: @Faisal: have you already managed to read the .csv file? Please show the current state of your code...

Comment: What is your data structure?

Comment: Can you fix your design?

Comment: I have tried this way to read the csv but it is a static way-                                        var avgs=d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.key;})                                                             
    .rollup(function(d) {
      return {
        value: d.value1 + d.value2 + d.value3 + d.value4;};
    })
    .entries(csv);

Answer (score 1):

Are you making an AJAX request for the CSV?  If you want to process it in there:

```
d3.csv("data.csv")
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      key: d.key,
      mySum: ((+d.value1) + (+d.value2) + (+d.value3) + (+d.value4))
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, rows) {
    console.log(rows);
  });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kthDLF2Zx2WKBG4kYMsN?p=preview).

**Edited for Comments**

If you don't know the number of columns, do something like this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv")
  .row(function(d) { 
    var mySum = 0;
    for (var o in d) { // iterate all the properties of d
      if (o === "key") continue; // if it's our key field skip it
      else mySum += +d[o]; // everyone else into the sum
    }
    return {
      key: d.key, 
      mySum: mySum
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, rows) { 
    console.log(rows); 
  });
```

Updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kthDLF2Zx2WKBG4kYMsN?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks. But I need to get the sum in a dynamic way rather attaching the column name like d.value1, d.value2 etc. As the case of number of column is more than 100, I should make it dynamic way to make it user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but anyway someone might need it. d3 has a sum method. ie:

```
var data = `key,value1,value2,value3,value4
mike,1,3,5,7
mila,2,4,6,8
minda,9,11,13,15`;
var summedData = d3.csvParse(data, function (d, i, columns) 
          { d3.autoType(d);
            d.total = d3.sum(columns, c => d[c]);
            return d;
          });
      
console.log(summedData);
```

Attaches row "total" to each row.